# Flutter can not upload File to Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am simply trying to upload an image using **Firebase CloudFirestore/Storage**. This is my method for it:

```
Future<void> uploadFile() async {
    File file = File(croppedImagePath);

    try {
      int randomNumber = Random().nextInt(10000);
      String imageLocation = 'images/image$randomNumber.jpg';

      await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(imageLocation).putFile(file); // <- crash
      _addPathToDatabse(imageLocation);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      // e.g, e.code == 'canceled'
      print(e.message);
    }
  }
```

but this crashes with:

> Exception has occurred.
> MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Task#startPutFile on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage))

This is what I added in `pubspec.yaml` :

```
  firebase_core: ^1.3.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.3.0
  firebase_storage: ^9.0.0
```

I tried running `flutter clean` and also restarted the project several times... What am I missing here? Why is it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after running `Flutter clean`, restarting my pc and deleting my derived data it is working again...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you check if the file is correct, you can also try converting your file to bytes.

Comment: I dont think this has anything to do with the file... Then the putFile would throw an error. But Flutter cant find putFile because of some dependency error *i think*